# Clear last two characters in MySQL string

Tags: php, mysql

My query is:

```
SELECT IDebook, AUTOR, TITLE, FILE, M_01, M_02, M_03, M_04, M_05, M_06, M_07, M_08, M_09, M_10 FROM ebook WHERE OBJAVA=1 AND LANG='en' ORDER BY ebook.IDebook DESC
```

HTML code:

```
<?php if (!empty($row_article['M_01'])) { ?>children's, <?php } ?>
<?php if (!empty($row_article['M_02'])) { ?>crime, <?php } ?>
<?php if (!empty($row_article['M_03'])) { ?>fiction, <?php } ?>
<?php if (!empty($row_article['M_04'])) { ?>horror, <?php } ?>
<?php if (!empty($row_article['M_05'])) { ?>humor, <?php } ?>
<?php if (!empty($row_article['M_06'])) { ?>mystery, <?php } ?>
<?php if (!empty($row_article['M_07'])) { ?>romance, <?php } ?>
<?php if (!empty($row_article['M_08'])) { ?>science fiction, <?php } ?>
<?php if (!empty($row_article['M_09'])) { ?>thriller, <?php } ?>
<?php if (!empty($row_article['M_10'])) { ?>young adult, <?php } ?>
<?php if (!empty($row_article['M_11'])) { ?>open 1, <?php } ?>
<?php if (!empty($row_article['M_12'])) { ?>open 2, <?php } ?>
```

Result is for example:
"children's, humor, fiction,"

How do I delete the last comma?

Comment: This is a conceptually simple problem to fix, but your PHP code is too clunky and verbose to allow for a sleak solution, at least not that I can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is to [buffer your output](http://php.net/outcontrol), and remove the trailing comma and space with [trim](http://php.net/trim)

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<?php if (!empty($row_article['M_01'])) { ?>children's, <?php } ?>
<?php if (!empty($row_article['M_02'])) { ?>crime, <?php } ?>
<?php if (!empty($row_article['M_03'])) { ?>fiction, <?php } ?>
<?php if (!empty($row_article['M_04'])) { ?>horror, <?php } ?>
<?php if (!empty($row_article['M_05'])) { ?>humor, <?php } ?>
<?php if (!empty($row_article['M_06'])) { ?>mystery, <?php } ?>
<?php if (!empty($row_article['M_07'])) { ?>romance, <?php } ?>
<?php if (!empty($row_article['M_08'])) { ?>science fiction, <?php } ?>
<?php if (!empty($row_article['M_09'])) { ?>thriller, <?php } ?>
<?php if (!empty($row_article['M_10'])) { ?>young adult, <?php } ?>
<?php if (!empty($row_article['M_11'])) { ?>open 1, <?php } ?>
<?php if (!empty($row_article['M_12'])) { ?>open 2, <?php } ?>
<?php
    $string = ob_get_clean();
    echo trim($string, ' ,'); // remove all leading and trailing spaces  and commas
?>
```

This is not the most efficient way to do it, but it will cause the least amount of changes to your existing code.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to iterate over all columns, adding all non-empty values to a result array. Then in the end, [implode](http://php.net/implode) or [join](http://php.net/join) this array into a comma+space-delimited string.

```
$values = [];
$strings = [
    1 => 'children\'s',
    2 => 'crime',
    3 => 'fiction',
    4 => 'horror',
    ...
];

foreach (range(1, 12) as $id) {
    $idStr = str_pad($id, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    if (!empty($row_article['M_' . $idStr])) {
        $values[] = $strings[$id];
    }
}
echo implode(', ', $values);
```